# In postgres is it possible to recover from lock_timeout within a transaction?

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, I am trying to call `pg_advisory_xact_lock` using `lock_timeout` to set the wait time.

The issue I see is that if the `lock_timeout` ellapses, it kills the transaction, returning an error code 25P02. I'd rather have the transaction survive and just that one statement die.

I'm wondering if I can do this via the `DO $$ BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END $$` construct to catch the `lock_timeout` error; however, it seems that the DO block can't return results and does not support OUT parameters.

Is there a supported pattern in postgres for calling a function like this without dooming the transaction on timeout?

Comment: Instead of a  `DO` block you could write a PL/pgSQL function and call that from the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function with an `EXCEPTION` handler, or you can set savpoints directly:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SAVEPOINT p;

SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(4711);

-- if there is an error
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a;
```

Comment: I ended up using save points. Thanks!